# Is my answer correct? Partitioning numbers

Tags: integer-partitions

How many ways are there to write the number 7 with the summands: 1, 2, and 3? 
For example, there are 7 ways to write the number 4:

{1 + 1 + 1 + 1}  x 1

{2 + 1 + 1} x 3

{3 + 1} x 2

{2 + 2} x 1

I got the answer 44 by doing so:

{1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1} x 1

{2 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1} x 6

{3 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1} x 5

{2 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 1} x 12

{2 + 2 + 1 + 1} x 4

{3 + 2 + 2 + 1} x 12

{3 + 3 + 1} x 3

{3 + 2 + 2} x 3

The problem is, Im likely to miss a kind of summand, for example I forgot there is {2 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 1}, any tips on how to list them all? And how to get the cool number fonts people use here? Thanks!

Comment: The 'cool' font is called LaTeX and tutorials are found https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Comment: Note that the word *partition* (used in title but not body of your Question) means the summands are considered without regard to order, i.e. rearrangement of summands is not counted as a different solution.  The word *composition* is used to describe summations where the order of terms is important.

Comment: Thanks landuros

Comment: And thanks hardmath

Comment: Ordered partitions enumerate to $2^n$. {2 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 1} x 12 should be $\times 10$... see if you can get $64$ with all the partitions of $6$.

Comment: Where is 3+2+1+1?

Comment: I did a typo, I wrote 3+2+2+1 instead

Answer (score 2):

In your counting the order of the summands is playing a rôle. Denote the number of representations of $n$ by summands $1$, $2$, $3$ by $a_n$. Any such representation has a last summand from $\{1,2,3\}$. Therefore we have the following recursion:
$$a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}\qquad(n\geq3)\ .\tag{1}$$
The initial values are $a_0=a_1=1$, $a_2=2$, and we then obtain $a_3=4$, $a_4=7$. The [general solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients) of $(1)$ is obtained through solution of its characteristic equation $\lambda^3-\lambda^2-\lambda-1=0$.

Comment: These are the "tribonacci" numbers : https://oeis.org/A000073 (See in particular the second comment)